# Create Hash column in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create an extra column (using PHP and mysql) in my table that contains a random key. Maybe I could hash data from the row table to have unique values. Please I need suggestions.

Comment: First you should add the column manually in your phpmyadmin GUI, to have a unique hash you could use `sha1($some_index)` (assuming you have an id column for each element, or you could use the current timestamp `sha1(time())` the `time()` function only contain second so if you it will be ok only if you can't have multiple request per second.

Answer (score 4):

using a timestamp as a source for a hash should be enough to get a unique hash. Better to use microtime() instead of time() because there could be 2 requests in the same second.

```
$hash = sha1(microtime());
```